# For newbie : Test with rspec in a model using a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a `Ownership` model, that has a `start_date` and a `end_date` and in my model, I have the following code :

```rb
def current?
  self.start_date.present? && self.end_date.nil?
end
```

Now I want to test `ownership.current?`

How am I going to do that ? Here what I tried, using expect...

```rb
describe "when owning and giving date are nil" do
  before do
    @ownership.agreed = true
    @ownership.save
    @ownership.update_attributes(start_date: nil, end_date: nil)
  end
  it { should be_valid }
  expect(@ownership.current?).to be_false

  describe "then product is owned" do
    before { @ownership.update_attributes(start_date: 1.day.ago) }

    it { should be_valid }
    expect(@ownership.current?).to be_true

    describe "then product is given" do
      before { @ownership.update_attributes(end_date: 1.hour.ago) }

      it { should be_valid }
      expect(@ownership.current?).to be_false
    end
  end
end
```

... but it didn't worked. I tried to replace `expect(@ownership.current?).to be_false` by `@ownership.current? { should be_false }`, but it didn't worked out either.

Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd only test the two outcomes for current?

```rb
describe OwnerShip do
  it "#current? returns false" do
    ownership.current?.should be_false
  end

  context "when started and not yet ended" do
    it "#current? returns true" do
      ownership.start_date = Date.today
      ownership.end_date = nil
      ownership.current?.should be_true
    end
  end
end
```